# ADSL upload speed low on PC, but good with phone over wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet-connection, adsl

on PC over LAN:

[image]

on Android phone over wifi:

[image]

ADSL status on my router:

[image]

These speed tests were run on the same time on same router.

My router brand is TPLink. I have tried new cables with all 4 ports.

My upload speed is 1M, so can anyone help me to get it on my PC?

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question.

Comment: Sorry. Edited. Can you answer now?

Comment: You need to narrow down the issue first. If you plug the computer directly into the modem, do you still see the same upload speed? If the answer is yes, then there is likely something wrong with your NIC or its settings (check link rate, duplexing, etc). If it goes up to what it should be, then it is an issue with your router.

Comment: The problem seem to happen only with that particular PC. The reason could be with NIC. Thanks!